# alerting an input value onclicking a label with for='' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i have the following code

```js
    $('.ale').click(function(){
      var val = $('.val').val();
      alert(val);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <label class='ale' for='hello'>
    <input class='val' type='text' id='hello' value='Hello'>
    
    <label class='ale' for='world'>
    <input class='val' type='text' id='world' value='World'>
```

In this code, I'm trying to make a script that alert the `value` of the `input` by clicking on its `label`

but that won't work since it always gets the first `value = 'Hello'`

How can i define the onclick to get the value of the input that its `id attr = for attr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the value of `for` attribute of label and use it find input with same `id` value.

```js
    $('.ale').click(function(){
      var val = $(this).attr('for');
      alert($('#'+val).val());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <label class='ale' for='hello'>Label 1</label>
    <input class='val' type='text' id='hello' value='Hello'>
    
    <label class='ale' for='world'>Label 2</label>
    <input class='val' type='text' id='world' value='World'>
```

Comment: @AXAI fixed that. Missed out on closing label tags while editing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('.ale').click(function () {
  var val = $(this).next('.val').val()
  alert(val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class='ale' for='hello'>Label 1</label>
<input class='val' type='text' id='hello' value='Hello'>
    
<label class='ale' for='world'>Label 2</label>
<input class='val' type='text' id='world' value='World'>
```

Comment: What would happen if the next `.val` doesn't exist?

Comment: @AXAI it'll return undefined

Answer (score 0):

when using `$('.val')` you get all the instances of the class val of your code.

use `$(this).next('input').val();`

Comment: Your answer assumes that there's `input` element immediately after `label`. What if user wants to get value of any input text field on the page.